# installing scikit-learn in mac. wrong xcode detected

Tags: xcode, macos, scikit-learn

i'm running osx 10.8.5. and xcode 5.1.1.
when i run

```
sudo port install py27-scikit-learn
```

i'm getting the following message

```
Error: The installed version of Xcode (2.0orlower) is too old to use on the installed OS version. Version 4.6.2 or later is recommended on Mac OS X 10.8.
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port py27-scikit-learn failed
```

I am so confused. In my /Applications folder, when i run Xcode, it reports 5.11.
when i run

```
xcode-select -print-path
```

i'ts pointing to the right directory

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

how do i solve this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me 4 hours to figure out: gist.github.com/xlfe/7786057

Edit - Included content from link:

```
# Pre-requsites:
# X-code 5.0.1 with command line tools
# Homebrew, homebrew python, homebrew pip

export CFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
export FFLAGS="-m32 -m64"
export LDFLAGS="-Wall -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle -arch i386 -arch x86_64"
export CC=gcc-4.2
export CXX="g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64"
brew install gfortran
brew install apple-gcc42
pip install cython

#use existing brews
brew tap samueljohn/python
brew tap homebrew/science
pip install nose

#installs numpy as a dependency
brew install scipy

pip install scikit-learn
```

Comment: Please elaborate more on your answer